# SQL Server Contains search

Tags: sql-server, contains

I have a table called `Employee` like this:

```
 empid       name              city
-------------------------------------
 1      Dhoni and Virat        Pune
 2      Raina or Rahane        Delhi
 3      John                   CA  
 4      Dhoni                  Chennai
 5      Virat                  Mumbai
```

I am using contains search in the table. When I run this query, I am not able to get the exact the results in the correct order.

```
SELECT name 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE CONTAINS(name,'"Dhoni and Virat"') 
ORDER BY ASC
```

I am getting the results in the below order.

```
Dhoni
Virat
Dhoni and Virat
```

But I want those results in the following order

```
Dhoni and Virat
Dhoni
Virat
```

Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: Can you show us more data so that it is clear how you want to sort?

Comment: Let us consider the below example. I want to perform search with the following name "Micheal and Madhana". When i search with that name, I want the data to be displayed in the following order.    1.Micheal and Madhana * 2. Micheal * 3. Madhana * .......  Such a way i want the results to be displayed. But here, it is displaying  in different order as below 1. Micheal * 2.Madhana * 3.Micheal and Madhana*.....

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY empid ASC` will give the result in your required order

```
SELECT name 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE CONTAINS(name,'"Dhoni and Virat"') 
ORDER BY empid ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with Order by name asc. but it returns the results in different order. it is not returning with proper order. when i run the above query, each word it is taking and perform contains search. it is not taking the whole word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "like" instead

```
SELECT name
FROM `employee`
WHERE `name` LIKE '%Dhoni%' or `name` LIKE '%Virat%'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know, we can use like operation. But the reason why i went for contains is , performance wise, it is faster than like operation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [CONTAINSTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx)?

```
SELECT e.name 
FROM EMPLOYEE e
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(EMPLOYEE, name,'"Dhoni" or "Virat"') as con 
    ON e.empid = con.[KEY]
ORDER BY con.RANK DESC
```